# About exterior measure of union of two disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm reading *Real Analysis* by Stein and Shakarchi and have trouble understanding the part that is highlighted below.

Chapter 1, Observation 4: If $E=E_1\cup E_2$ and $d(E_1,E_2)>0$, then $m_*(E)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$. Here $d(E_1,E_2)=\inf |x-y|$ where the inf is taken over all $x\in E_1,y\in E_2$.

Proof: By countable subadditivity, $m_*(E)\leq m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$. It suffices to prove the reverse inequality now. Choose $\delta$ s.t. $d(E_1,E_2)>\delta>0$. Choose a covering $E\subset \cup_j Q_j$ of closed cubes s.t. $\sum_j |Q_j|\leq m_*(E)+\epsilon$. We may, after subdividing the cubes $Q_j$, assume that each $Q_j$ has a diameter less than $\delta$. In this case, each $Q_j$ can intersect at most one of the two sets $E_1,E_2$. Let $J_1,J_2$ be the sets of indices $j$ for which $Q_j$ intersects $E_1,E_2$ respectively. Then $J_1\cap J_2$ is empty and
$$E_1\subset \cup_{j\in J_1}Q_j, E_2\subset \cup_{j\in J_2}Q_j$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2) &\leq \sum_{j\in J_1} |Q_j| + \sum_{j\in J_2} |Q_j| \\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty |Q_j| \\
&\leq m_*(E)+\epsilon
\end{align*}

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, the proof is complete.

> I understand the above proof but didn't understand the following line at the end of section 2 in chapter 1: *One cannot conclude in general that if $E_1\cup E_2$ is a disjoint union of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, then $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)=m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$.*

But isn't this is what is proved in observation 4? If $d(E_1,E_2)>0$, then $E_1,E_2$ are disjoint, so I don't understand why this comment is made?

Comment: If $E_1,E_2$ are disjoint but not necessarily satisfy $d(E_1,E_2)>0$ then the additivity of $m_*$ will not necessarily hold for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d(E_1,E_2)>0$, then $E_1,E_2$ are disjoint but the converse is false. If $E_1=\mathbb N$ and $E_2=\{n+\frac 1 n: n \geq 2\}$ then $E_1$ and $E_2$ are disjoint  but $d(E_1,E_2)=0$ . Disjointness is a weaker hypothesis and it is not sufficient for $m_*(E_1\cup E_2)= m_*(E_1)+m_*(E_2)$.